# Nested IF using query in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, nested, conditional-statements

I am having trouble on this code. It does not go to the 3rd condition base on query.
I have 5 columns to work with.

AMIN  AMOUT  PMIN  PMOUT STATUS

First entry creates record is there no record for that date and student. Column: AMIN with status of 0
It should update on column AMOUT and STATUS to 1
Next, should update PMIN with STATUS of 2
lastly updates PMOUT with status of 3.

This code works only up to PMIN then updates AMOUT the updates PMIN. it does not go to PMOUT

I have this code:

```
<?php
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE STUDENTID='$id' AND LOGDATE='$date'";
        $query=$conn->query($sql);
        if($query->num_rows>0){
            $sql1 ="SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE STUDENTID='$id' AND LOGDATE='$date' AND STATUS='1'";
            $query1=$conn->query($sql1);
            if($query1->num_rows>0){
                $sql2 ="SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE STUDENTID='$id' AND LOGDATE='$date' AND STATUS='2'";
                $query2=$conn->query($sql2);
                if($query2->num_rows>0){
                    $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET PMOUT='$time', STATUS='3' WHERE STUDENTID='$studentID' AND LOGDATE='$date'";
                    $query=$conn->query($sql);
                    $_SESSION['success'];
                }
                else{
                $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET PMIN='$time', STATUS='2' WHERE STUDENTID='$studentID' AND LOGDATE='$date'";
                $query=$conn->query($sql);
                $_SESSION['success'];
                }
            }
            else{
            $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET AMOUT='$time', STATUS='1' WHERE STUDENTID='$studentID' AND LOGDATE='$date'";
            $query=$conn->query($sql);
            
            }
        
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance(STUDENTID,AMIN,LOGDATE,STATUS) VALUES('$studentID','$time','$date','0')";
            if($conn->query($sql) ===TRUE){
                 $_SESSION['success'];
            }else{
            $_SESSION['error'] = $conn->error;
            }   
        }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: *I have 5 columns to work with.* No, provide complete CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STUDENTID` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `AMIN` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `AMOUT` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `PMIN` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PMOUT` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOGDATE` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

Comment: Please do not post facts as comments - add them to the question text (use Edit link under it).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need:

1. Create unique index by student and date:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_student_date ON attendance (studentid, logdate);
```

2. Use the next query:

```sql
INSERT INTO attendance (studentid, logdate, amin, amout, pmin, pmout, status)
VALUES ($id, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
amout = CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN CURRENT_TIME ELSE amout END,
pmin = CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN CURRENT_TIME ELSE pmin END,
pmout = CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN CURRENT_TIME ELSE pmout END,
status = status + 1;
```

If the row for current student and date not exists then it will be created, if it exists then it will be updated according to your algorithm. Your nested IFs in PHP not needed.

---

Additionally I recommend you to alter datatypes which must match the data stored in.

- `logdate` should be `DATE NOT NULL`
- `amin, amout, pmin, pmout` should be `TIME`
- `status` should be `TINYINT CHECK (status BETWEEN 0 AND 3)`

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=636cb69a8e9be5e58000115ac1cc6248)

Comment: So it will just one query? I will try...

Comment: @JohnArzaga *So it will just one query?* yes. See the fiddle by provided link.

Comment: These is awesome! thank you man. Very nice and safe technique. I always think of doing this procedural. Now I have started to learn. I want to know more about sql procedures.
THANK YOU AGAIN. It saves my day.

Comment: @JohnArzaga You may use the query itself, not stored proc. I create SP only for not to repeat this long SQL text purposes.